# Why is it required to use a new Spark Session after writing a streaming dataframe into an Iceberg table to show new changes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-iceberg

If you use a spark session to create an Iceberg table with Spark scala in batch mode, and after that you do a writestream process with a merge into operation it's not possible to see new changes with spark session used in batch process.

You need to create a new one to see the actual state of the table. Why this happen?

write batch is done like this

`df.writeTo(tableName).createOrReplace()`

write streaming is done using these methods

```
override def write(df: DataFrame): StreamingQuery = {

  implicit val spark: SparkSession = df.sparkSession

  df.writeStream
    .format("iceberg")
    .trigger(Trigger.Once())
    .option("fanout-enabled", "true")
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
    .foreachBatch(mergeDFIntoTable _)
    .outputMode("update")
    .start()
}
```

```
private def mergeDFIntoTable(df: DataFrame, batchId: Long): Unit = {
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("source_table")
  val mergeSQL: String =
    s"""
      |MERGE INTO $TableIdentifier t
      |USING source_table s
      |ON s.identifier = t.identifier
      |WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
      |WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
      |""".stripMargin

  logger.info(s"BATCH ID: $batchId | SQL: $mergeSQL")

  // The streaming query uses a cloned Spark Session from the original session that created it.
  df.sparkSession.sql(mergeSQL)
  df.unpersist()
}
```

If I use first spark session created and I read the table after batch process and again after streaming, show is the same (without adding or updating new rows)

`spark.table(tableName).show()`

However if after streaming process I create a new Spark Session the show process after streaming reflects the changes

`val newSparkSession = spark.newSession()`

`newSparkSession.table(tableName).show()`

Comment: Can you paste the code that doing `show`? `show` also is a `LIMIT` query. You can try more specific query like `spark.sql("select * from target_table where key = .. ")` to verify new `key` data is there or not.